# What is the next step when an 'ask ubuntu' question isn't answered?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question months ago (back on 16 January 2015) about an 'invalid argument' when trying to access a shared folder on an external drive usb connected to a Win 8.1 box on my network.  The question has been viewed 260 times, voted for a couple of times, commented on by another user with the same problem, but NEVER ANSWERED.   I am tired of using my workaround remote desktopping to yet another windows box on the network. I did not originally, and am still reluctant to, notify it as a bug, because I am not sufficiently familiar with this OS to be confident that it is.  I would now like to know where I should post my original question to get it answered?

Comment: Check out this site : http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Comment: I've started a bounty on it. Comment if/when you get a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the [help](https://askubuntu.com/help/no-one-answers)

> **What should I do if no one answers my question?**
>
> First, make sure you’ve asked a good question. To get better answers, you may need to put additional effort into your question. Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.

Basically:

1. you add a bounty to it or ask in chat if someone could put a bounty on it.
2. you include more information to the question.

By the way in case someone is wondering: [Failed to mount Windows share: Invalid argument](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574393/failed-to-mount-windows-share-invalid-argument) A quick search on the web made me add a comment to your question ;)

Comment: Also I would add to this, update your tags, you can have five, different users look for different tags based on there skill sets, setting these right can make all the difference

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more descriptive of the problem and post more information.

Simply stating something is broken does not do much to solve the problem.

See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Check your logs, try to mount the share manually from the command line, read the documentation, google search samba or file sharing.

It also appears you are running Linux Mint, which is not Ubuntu, seek support from the mint community.

If all else fails, your problem may be local or unique to your situation.

If education (read the documentation), google search, and refining the question do not help, file a quality bug report. If you are using Mint, file first with Mint.

Comment: The OP seems to be using both Ubuntu and Mint ("the only *other* Linux box on the network which runs Mint Cinnamon").